# How to use truncate with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, pipe, truncate, ngx-translate

I am trying to truncate string after it gets translated. I need help on how to use truncate after the string gets translated.

```
< span class="inputName" translate>{{ TIMESLOT_1 | truncate:[4] }}
< /span>
```

I've attempted the method above, but that results in this error:

> **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution. Use truncate pipe after translate in innerHTML.

```
< span class="inputName" [innerHTML]=" 'TIMESLOT_1' | translate | truncate: [4]" translate>  
< /span>
```